# Android Floating label on click

Tags: android, button, label, action, floating

I am trying to add labels on the right of my Floating Action Buttons which will be shown when the main button is pressed and those would be appear. I made some tries but either I make the text appears before I press the main button, or, the text never appears..

It would be great if someone could spot me the problem on my code. I am really stuck.. Thanks!!

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@drawable/main"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/whitetransp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fabLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fab1"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/whitetransp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FabTitle1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fab1"
        android:visible="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the visibility property of the controls

Comment: I don't get it.. Could you help me a little more? Thank you!

Comment: Every control in android(buttons,textboxes, floating action buttons,etc) has visibility property. It is a boolean value which can be set to true or false. So to use that if you are setting the property in your layout.xml file you can use `android:visible="true"` or if you are setting the property in your java file you can use `VISIBILITY.VISIBLE` property

Comment: I made some changes on my code but still I don't have any result.. Could you have a look?? Thank you!